# Which waterproof overshoes would you recommend for use with clipless pedal shoes?

Tags: clothes, clipless, shoes, spd

Last Winter I bought some waterproof overshoes on the internet to keep my feet dry on the daily commute. Unfortunately these overshoes fastened with a velcro strap which fastened underneath the shoe obscuring the cleats in both my road shoes (SPD-SL) and mountain bike shoes (SPD). I managed to get by tucking the velcro straps inside the overshoes and wearing them loose, but they have never really stayed secure that way.

Can anyone recommend some waterproof overshoes that:

- Keep your feet dry
- Fit snugly and don't come undone on a ride or catch on the bike
- Have fittings which don't obscure cleats and work well with clipless pedals
- Are reasonably priced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to use the Endura neoprene overshoes commuting through the UK winters. They were very warm and good at keeping out the water, but they were way too fragile. They just about made it through a second winter but had little splits and tears all over them. I reckon they'd be excellent if you were just out for a long ride in the country, but if your commute involves traffic lights where you put your foot, down then sooner or later you'll kick the kerb or the pedal and tear the neoprene.

Although it's not quite what you asked for, my advice would be to splash out on some waterproof shoes. I hunted round for a bargain pair of [Specialized Defrosters](http://www.specialized.com/us/en/bc/SBCEqProduct.jsp?spid=58001) which are [brilliant](http://www.bikeradar.com/gear/category/clothing/shoes/product/review-specialized-bicycles-bg-defroster-mtb-shoe-30858/) for winter MTBing and commuting - I probably wear them for half the year now.

Answer (score 1):

For serious winter riding (I rode for 12 years all year round in Toronto, Canada, and while we had reasonable weather, it did get wet, cold, and icky a lot) I gave up on clipless, and just used platforms with a pair of hunting boots!  Canadian Tire sold -40C and -70C versions.  (I rode in -35C in the -70C pair, and I gotta say, my toes were quite comfy!)

Tuck a pair of ski pants or waterproof pants over the tops, and that was the driest I ever attained in bad weather.

They bend surprisingly well so pedaling is not the issue, and you have good stability in bad weather.  You know, if you are sliding, and put down both feet with those big boots, you might still slide a distance, but you can control it better.

I never tried anything like you suggest, as based on other waterproof clothes, once it gets wet enough, nothing is water proof.  Everything has holes, seals, zippers, seams, etc...  They help, no argument, but not all the way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in the UK, may I recommend one of my favourite brands?

Check out the Endura neoprene ones, neoprene works great at any temperature above -5 degrees when they suddenly give up on keeping you warm. You can also wash them and they will take the abuse. The Endura ones are widely available, made in the Far East rather than Scotland (where the posh Endura coats are made).

If you want budget, what shoe size are you? Far too often overshoes can get in the bargain bin of a bike shop as the middle sizes sell out leaving dwarf and giant sizes only. Look out for some bargain bin Altura (or other make/models). Get lucky and you can pick up a set for £10 from a shop that does road bikes.

Answer (score -1):

Gotex socks. Yes, they sound gimmicky and uncomfortable. However, I used to hike 20 to 30 miles a day in boggy terrain, and my feet stayed toasty warm and dry! You should wear thin merino wool socks inside for best effect. That said, REI sells waterproof biking socks for cheaper made for the job.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  The question was about overshoes; GoreTex socks might keep ones feet dry, but would still require cleaning and drying out the shoes, so this isn't really the answer the question was looking for.

Comment: Is there is need to down vote me just because I offered an alternative solution? After all the question poster is having problems with over-shoes.  I offered a valid answer because I used to commute via bicycle to college in the wet NW of England back in the days with Shimano SPDs. Gortex socks were the only workable solution before purpose made wet biking socks. It didn't matter how wet my shoes got, but my feet maintained dry. And I walked around campus in my MTB SPD shoes just fine bc they dry off reasonably quick.